# Having trouble logging into openwrt

Tags: raspberry-pi, openwrt

I just installed OpenWRT on my Raspberry PI but couldn't log in.

The port scan shows that ports 22, 23 and 53 are open, but I don't know the default SSH password (tried root/admin but that does not work) and telnet doesn't work either.

The image comes from the latest posts of OpenWRT: openwrt-brcm2708-sdcard-vfat-ext4.img.
Is port 80 supposed to be open and if it is not, what can I do about it?

Comment: There is no default password after installing OpenWRT. Telnet should work. How do you connect to RP with telnet? Try: `telnet 192.168.1.1`. See [here](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/firstlogin)

Answer (score 1):

First login to OpenWrt is different: telnet as root with no password until you set it. More here -> http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/firstlogin